# Getting maxSize for data region in Apache Ignite

Tags: caching, memory, ignite, metrics

> I am Using Apache Ignite 2.8.0.
>   Now my persistence is disabled, and i was set my maxSize as 400Mib by,

```
 <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
    <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
            <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
             <property name="name" value="Default_Region1"/> 
             <!-- Setting the size of the default region to 4GB. -->
            <property name="maxSize" value="#{400L * 1024 * 1024 }"/> 
              <!--<property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/> -->
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Now i am running this in my browser,

```
http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=dataregion
```

> this is my response for Default_Region1,

```
{"name":"Default_Region1","totalAllocatedPages":0,"totalUsedPages":0,"totalAllocatedSize":0,"allocationRate":0.0,"evictionRate":0.0,"largeEntriesPagesPercentage":0.0,"pagesFillFactor":0.0,"dirtyPages":0,"physicalMemoryPages":0,"physicalMemorySize":0,"usedCheckpointBufferPages":0,"usedCheckpointBufferSize":0,"checkpointBufferSize":0,"pageSize":4096,"offHeapSize":0,"pagesReplaceRate":0.0,"pagesReplaced":0,"pagesReplaceAge":0.0,"offheapUsedSize":0,"pagesRead":0,"pagesWritten":0}
```

> i didn't find the maxSize as 400Mib in response, How can i get that my MaxSize is 400Mib by using http request?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about HTTP, but `DataRegionMetricsMXBean` has `getMaxSize()` accessor.

You can execute compute tasks from REST so you can implement a task that does that, call it via [`exe` REST call](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/restapi#execute).

Comment: yeas.. but i want by rest API.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is available by REST API yet.

Comment: then how gridgain web console got that value?

Comment: I think it uses some kind of internal task. You can run compute tasks via REST and get results.

Comment: How can i compute task via rest API? i need example of that , because it will be used in many places..